# Can't find mongo.exe (installed MongoDB through NPM)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm

I am studying Node.js with MongoDB in [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb.asp).
I have downloaded **MongoDB** using **NPM**.
`npm install mongodb`
  I wanted to check MongoDB version (to see if it's working) 
I tried :
`mongodb -version`
`mongodb --version`
Nothing worked. (I am using Windows 64 bit.)
I found the MongoDB folder under 'some folder name' > node_modules > mongodb
There was another folder called 'mongodb-core' 
I looked through them but couldn't find mongo.exe. They only had lots of js files.
I looked under Program Files and Program Files(x86), but no MongoDB folder.

**If I installed MongoDB through NPM, there is no mongo.exe? no folder under Program Files?**

`npm -version` 
6.9.0 
`node -v`
v10.15.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mongodb is a database not a node module. You have to download it from [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/)
according to your platform. After that, it will be installed in your os
in windows it will be in your *c/programsfiles*
and make a folder called 'data' in d drive
after that open terminal "

> C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin\

here then type "

> mongod.exe --dbpath D:\data"

that's it!

Comment: I feel dumb :(  Thank you. I downloaded MongoDB and it is working. I was downloading a mongoDB driver through npm not MongoDB.  I am dumb. haha but at least now I know. Thank you again.